# Followed the instruction, but can't deploy React app on Github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, create-react-app, github-pages

I'm not able to deploy my react app on github pages.
Followed all the instructions - added "homepage", "predeploy" and "deploy", build it with "npm run build" and pushed updated code again to the github page, but whenever I clicked the link it shows Getting Started with Created React App instruction instead.
Oh, and changed the source to 'gh-pages' for my app as well.

My app: https://sopspops.github.io/weather-app/
You can check all the code here: https://github.com/sopspops/weather-app

Please help! Thank you!!

Comment: Looks like you figured it out? Try incognito if you're not seeing it. 

Although, you might not want to leave it up forever, because your API key will be exposed on the site.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't edit anything but checking it again after a couple of hours, now I see it's working now. :) 
Oh... I thought I hide my API key, can you see it?

Comment: AFAIK there are no secrets on the front end, you'd have to create a backend server to hide it. You created environmental variables, but they resolve on the frontend so they're just plaintext (It starts with abb7 and ends with 5b1e). As long as you didn't provide a credit card it doesn't really matter though.

Comment: Oh... thought as long as I put my 'secrets' in .gitignore file, I'd be safe. Thank you fo letting me know!!! You have a good day :D